# How to make swing apps look like native apps of a platform

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a Java project. Since Java main feature is portability, I want my application to look like a native windows app when run on windows or a native Mac app when run on mac.So how to I achieve that with Swing?

Comment: By restyling the UI for the corresponding platform

Comment: Did you try google first? This is very common thing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing supports Look&Feels to alter how components behave and are displayed.
For each platform, there is a **System Look&Feel** which mimics the underlying platform:

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to do it as in in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#programmatic ?